# Не могу создать слушающий сокет в powershell

Tags: powershell, tcplistener

Команда:

```
$listener = new-object Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1', 81)
```

Ошибка:

```
new-object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "No connection could be made because the target machine actively
refused it 127.0.0.1:81"
At line:1 char:13
+ $listener = new-object Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1', 81)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

При этом 127.0.0.1 пингуется и я открыл 81ый порт (на вход и выход)

Подскжаите пожалуйста, что еще нужно сделать?

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Командой

```
$listener = new-object Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1', 81)
```

Вы пытаетесь подключится на 81 порт хоста `127.0.0.1`. Т.к. этот порт никто не слушает, вы получаете законную ошибку

Слушающий (серверный) сокет создается по другому

```
# Будем ждать подключений с любого адреса на 81 порт
$endpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([system.net.ipaddress]::any, 81)
# Создаем слушателя
$listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
# Запускаем слушателя
$listener.start()
# Ждем подключения новых клиентов
$client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
```